# Call specific method when delayed_job failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm looking for a way to do a specific treatment when a delayed_job failed on my rails app. I don't know if it's possible, and how I can configure DelayedJob for that.
I saw that I can add the `error` method for one specific job, but I want something similar for **all jobs**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a `Delayed::Plugin` and follow this tutorial:
http://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/delayed-jobs-callbacks-and-hooks-in-rails

You will be able to trigger an event for any job failure across your app.
For instance:

```html
require 'airbrake'
require 'delayed_job'

class AirbrakePlugin < Delayed::Plugin

  callbacks do |lifecycle|
    lifecycle.around(:invoke_job) do |job, *args, &block|
      begin
        # Forward the call to the next callback in the callback chain
        block.call(job, *args)
      rescue Exception => error
        ::Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(
            :error_class   => error.class.name,
            :error_message => "#{error.class.name}: #{error.message}",
            :backtrace => error.backtrace,
            :parameters    => {
                :failed_job => job.inspect
            }
        )
        # Make sure we propagate the failure!
        raise error
      end
    end
  end
```